# Software to track and enforce a specific configuration for various settings in Windows

Tags: windows, configuration-management

I have for a long time had my Windows update setting (located in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\Change settings`) set to *"Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them"*

(This is 64-bit Windows 7 Professional)

Today however for some reason I noticed a pop-up (in the notification area) that said that Windows has finished downloading the updates and will install them at next restart.

So for one reason or another something had changed the setting. I checked the questions about this at the superuser.SE (such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/859067/how-to-stop-windows-from-switching-back-to-install-updates-automatically) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/689526/windows-has-changed-to-download-and-install-updates-automatically)) but the answers were not applicable to my situation. Esp. since the answers discussed what may have caused the change and not so much how to - generally speaking - prevent it (besides completely stopping the Windows Update process which is not practical).

Anyway so what I wanted to ask is if anyone knows of open source software that can be used to control the configuration of a Windows system that is not part of a domain?

(Note that I do know that Group Policy can be (largely) used for this purpose. My reason for looking for an open source alternative is to check if I can tweak it for a specific purpose.)